# android all notification disappeared when open the app

Tags: java, android, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I'am using `FCM` for getting new notification which I am able to show without any problem but when i open the app all my notification disappeared

this my code for creating new notification

```
 final NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                mContext,mContext.getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id));

Notification notification;
        notification = mBuilder.setSmallIcon(icon).setTicker(title).setWhen(0)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
                .setStyle(inboxStyle)
                .setWhen(getTimeMilliSec(timeStamp))
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), icon))
                .setContentText(message)
                .build();

NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {



            CharSequence name = "my_channel";
            String Description = "This is my channel";
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
            NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(mContext.getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id), name, importance);
            mChannel.setDescription(Description);
            mChannel.enableLights(true);
            mChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
            mChannel.enableVibration(true);
            mChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400});
            mChannel.setShowBadge(false);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
        }


        int id = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
        notificationManager.notify(id, notification);
```

when click on a notification it opens an activity with extra data in
my intent

```
 Intent resultIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class); 
 resultIntent.putExtra("message", "wwwwwwww");
resultIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);


resultIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);



PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                PendingIntent.getActivity(
                        mContext,
                        0,
                        intent,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                );
```

now when i click on any notification it opens MainActivity with some extra value on which Main activity depends.

But when i click on a notification and it launches the activity all other notification disappeared.So, how can i prevent that and hide only clicked notification so user can see other notification

Comment: I think setting Autocancel false can work

Comment: i tried that same :/

Comment: How about `.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)`

Comment: giving different ids to notification may solve your problem. Pass the same id to pending intent too.

Comment: @primo `int id = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
        notificationManager.notify(id, notification);` already do that same

Comment: @JohnJoe same when open the app all Notification disappeared

Comment: how about in foreground ? will this happened also?

Comment: pass this id here also PendingIntent.getActivity(
                        mContext,
                        0,
                        intent,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                );
instead of 'zero' and then try

Comment: @primo same no thing

Comment: @JohnJoe i don't have service

Comment: try to give Pending Intent id different every time.  

PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                PendingIntent.getActivity(
                        mContext,
                        System.currentTimeMillis(),
                        intent,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                );

Comment: @SohelS9 i did that's same

Comment: remove this flag and try again 

resultIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

Answer (score 2):

not quite sure whether it'll work or not but can u please try with setting the request code unique rather than 0.

```
PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext,0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

replace 0 with the following

```
PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext,(int) System.currentTimeMillis(),intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Comment: not work .. this problem happen when only open MainActivity other activities work without disappearing notifiaction

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
**.setPriority(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH)**
Notification notification;
        notification = mBuilder.setSmallIcon(icon).setTicker(title).setWhen(0)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
                .setSound(alarmSound)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(message))
                .setWhen(getTimeMilliSec(timeStamp))
                .setSmallIcon(ICON)
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), icon))
                .setContentText(message)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setPriority(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH)
                .build();
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(num, notification);
```

Comment: why all notification gone when start MainActivity

Comment: because you have to set the  Priority for notification.

Comment: i try it before just show notification overlay when leave from MainActivity and back all notification gone

Comment: no thing new in your code only the Priority `**.setPriority(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH)**` and i tried it before if you read comment above on my question

Comment: okay then from any specific activity you back then notification clear or from any Activity you back then notification clears?

Comment: no only on MaicActivity i tried to make `PendingIntent`  to another `activity and notification still there` .. another try when i got notification i leave from app by home button and when i open the app again (Mainactivity) all notification gone